# ¿Porqué la visualización del console.log es distinta si tengo el mismo código en Datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Buscando una manera de obtener todos los datos de una tabla encontré en la [API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()) la función `tabla.rows().data()`. Miré también [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32041477/10053314) pregunta y me encontré con que el [ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/5uko1w3q/) mostrado en esa respuesta muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mientras el mío con exactamente la misma lógica en javascript muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código y el del ejemplo es el mismo

```
t = $('#Propiedades').DataTable();

    var data = t
            .rows()
            .data();

        console.log('The table has ' + data.length + ' records');
        console.log('Data', data);
```

Ésta es mi tabla

```
   <table id="Propiedades" class="display projects-table table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Propiedad</th>
                <th>Valor</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
   </table>
```

Está vacía ya que por medio de un `button` y por javascript le añado los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
t.row.add([
    prop,
    val
]).draw(false);
```

¿Por qué esa diferencia?¿Cómo puedo obtener solo los datos?

Comment: Aque se refiere que se ve distinto?, la unica diferencia que veo es que la del ejemplo tiene mas datos que los tuyos.

Comment: Qué versión de `DataTables` estas usando?

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa porque con el **mismo código** en una muestra unos datos y en la otra mas datos

Comment: Cuando llenas tu tabla por medio de un boton, cuantos registros agregas a la tabla?

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa Se añade de uno en uno, como puedes ver abajo

Comment: Pero si solo añades 3 registro a tu tabla, entonce en la consola veras 3, si añades 5, entonces en la consola veras 5.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa pero y el `ajax`,`cells`,`columns`...??? eso es lo que me interesa y lo que pregunto, los registros ya lo se, pero toda la informacion extra?

Comment: @NicolasOñate en el fiddle si abris la consola, despues el objeto y vas hasta el fondo aparece toda la información extra, pasa que al tener mas rows ocupa mas espacio

Comment: @Federico A mi no me ocurre eso, tan solo me lo muestra en mi código, he bajado hasta abajo del fiddle y después de todas las filas se finaliza

Comment: Podrias colocar una imagen de la parte final de cuando imprimes en consola. Es raro que no te aparezcan el resto de funciones.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa justo estaba comentandolo por el chat, he encontrado el fallo estaba con `row` y en la otra con `rows`

Comment: Que bueno que encontraste el problema. saludos.